# Postgis/Postgresql join 3 tables

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis, postgresql-9.2, cartography

I'm a complete beginner to Postgresql and Postgis and I can't figure how to do this:

I have 3 tables, `T1`, `T2` and `T3`. `T1` and `T2` have `ID` as common `column`. `T2` and `T3` can be joined on the `geom` column. `T1` and `T3` can't be joined.

In table 1, I have all the river names of my country. In table 3, I have all my data points (bound to table 2 by the `geom` column).

What I want is to add a column `name` to T3 which will tell me on what river this point lies.

I can bind `T1` and `T2` to have the name in `T2`. But I don't know how to continue and have this on `T3`.

What I have done, and this is really bad I know, is this:

```
ALTER TABLE T3 AS
WITH part1 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM T3 
    INNER JOIN T2 ON (the_geom = st_transform(geom_T3, 2154))
),
part2 AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
),
SET T1.name AS id 
FROM Part2;
```

Obviously that doesn't work at all.

I know that's a basic query so if you don't want to lose your time I'll understand :)

Also, I'm not English so forgive me for my mistakes.

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @Ganymede can you share your table structure for these 3 tables? I think an Alter Table command along with an Update query with a couple of joins would get the job done based on my understanding of the question but would help if you can share the schema

Comment: Sorry for what i'm asking but how to share the strusture of my tables?
With words that how they are:
T1: 3 columns like this : ident (names of points), geom (coordinates of points) ; 
T2: 2 colums:  ID, geom ; 
T3: 3 columns: ID, the_geom, River name;; 

T1 and T2 can be join with the geom column while T2 and T1 can be join by ID. I want to have the colum river on T1 to know on what river is my point.
Basically, T3 is my shape of river and T2 is the same thing but modified with pgrouting and in the process i lost the names of rivers.